# Can someone please help me verify if this is the correct way to set up an integral in spherical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

Let $W$ be the ice cream cone

$$W= \Big\{(x,y,z) | \sqrt{3x^2+3y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\Big\}$$ in spherical coordinates.

Is the correct answer

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/6}\int_{0}^{1} \rho^2 \sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

or is the answer

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/6}\int_{1}^{0} \rho^2 \sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

Since the region looks like this: [image]

And the radius goes from 1 to 0?

I can show my work for the remainder of the problem, but essentially I am just stuck on this one part for the bounds of $\rho$

Comment: Is the integral you're trying to evaluate
$$
\iiint_W\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dxdydz\ ?
$$
That's what your first integral in polar coordinates is equal to. Your second integral would evaluate to its negative.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\rho$ for radius, $\phi$ for latitude and $\theta$ for
longitude:

$$x = \rho  \cos\phi \cos\theta$$
$$y = \rho  \cos\phi \sin\theta$$
$$z = \rho  \sin\phi$$
$$
\rho\cos\phi \sqrt{3} \leq \rho\sin\phi\leq\sqrt{1-\rho^2\cos^2\phi}
\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\Longleftrightarrow
\tan \phi \geq \sqrt{3} \wedge \rho \leq 1
\Longleftrightarrow
\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \wedge \rho \leq 1
$$
And since in spehrical coordinates $dV = \rho^2 \cos\phi \;d\rho \;d\phi\;d\theta$
we get:

$$ 
V =
\int_0^{2\pi}
\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\int_0^1
\rho^2 \cos\phi \;d\rho \;d\phi\;d\theta
\;\;=\pi\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$

Comment: Thanks, actually a part of the question was to set it up in cylindrical and I got the same answer for that. But the other part of the question was to represent in spherical, which is why I was asking about that

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've posted the result in spherical coordinates.